# How to decrease RDP bandwidth usage?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, bandwidth, gaming

I am using Remote Desktop to connect to a Windows 7 x64 PC. The OS allows concurrent remote desktop connections.

I want to be able to play videogames remotely, but I noticed that when using remote desktop the game moves slowly, although when playing locally it moves OK. I mention that no other user was connected when playing.
I've noticed that the network throughput shown in task manager is around 75Mbps.

If I connect using AnyDesk, the network throughput is max. 10Mbps and the game moves OK. So this indicates that the problem is related with insufficient network bandwidth. But AnyDesk is not a solution since the PC needs to allow multiple concurrent remote desktop sessions.

I've tried lowering the settings of Remote Desktop to: 1024x764, 15 bit color, no other options allowed (e.g. visual styles, animation...), and the game moves a little bit better (not as good as when using AnyDesk), and the throughput drops to around 60Mbps. However, it is not acceptable for playing.

So my question is how can I lower the Remote Desktop throughput (to be able to play games as good as when using AnyDesk)?

Comment: What RDP client are you using?

Comment: I am using RDP 10.0.17134 (RDP protocol 10.5) on my PC (with Windows 10). On the remote PC it is RDP 6.3.9.6 (RDP protocol 8.1).

Answer (score 1):

Better solutions (if you have a recent GPU) would be Nvidia Gamestreaming or [Steam In-home Streaming](https://store.steampowered.com/streaming/) solutions which use your GPU hardware video encoder to capture and stream your games across the network.

Because they use hardware to capture and encode the video they can achieve much lower latency at much higher resolutions and because the video is encoded in h.264 it is much lower bandwidth than most RDP solutions.

RDP solutions tend to assume a 1:1 copy of your desktop is needed and speedy motion is less likely and so encode *everything* and they tend to do it slowly. For gaming your requirements are focused on low latency and fast motion response with a marginal loss of quality being acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried Nvidia SHIELD Gamestreaming with Moonlight client. It works OK, but the problem is that it does not connect if a user is logged in remotely. E.g., if a user is logged in locally, I can connect with Moonlight and play, but the user will see the game as I play it remotely (which is not desirable). If he is logged in remotely (via Remote Desktop), I cannot connect to play.

Comment: The Nvidia streaming solution basically takes control of the current desktop, like AnyDesk. It seems that RDP is the solution I need, only if it would allow to lower the bandwidth.